# Angular Animation Performance State/Transition vs Query

Tags: css, angular, performance, animation, browser

I am currently working with angular animations. Therefore I figured out two possible methods to attach animations to components. In the following I am describing them as State/Transition-Animations and Query-Animations.

**In this question I mainly want to know if there is a performance difference in going for one or the other way!?**

---

**1. State/Transition-Animations**

**.html**

```html
<div [@animation_foo]/>
```

**.ts**

```js
trigger('animation_foo', [
    state('true', style({...}),
    state('false', style({...})       
    transition('true => false', animate(...)
]
```

---

**2. Query-Animations**

**.html**

```html
<div [@animation_foo]>
    <div class="bar"/>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```js
trigger('animation_foo', [
    query('.bar', style({...}), animate('10ms', style({...}))
]
```

---

**Further thoughts:**

- My main **concern** with point **2. Query** is that:

1. If you do not have one query but multiple, which are combined via group(...) and the css selector is going to find elements on a deeper level (*'.foo > :nth-child(n+3) .bar'*) you have to iterate over a very big part of the DOM-Tree.
2. The stylings and animation applied to the elements happens after finding the element and before the animation - every time - because I expect, that it cannot be pre-compiled by the compiler?

- **Environment/Target platform:** I know it's might not related to a casual Web-Application, but I try to think in big enterprise applications with multiple router, nested components and lots of ngIf's ngFors, so that I personally can imagine that querying all that could be some effort.
- **Browser:** I know that browser differently behave differently. Personally I am interested only in Chrome for the moment - But for the sake of community a general answer would be awesome.

*If you have any further information that are important to note, it would be nice to share (bugs, ...)*

Comment: Have you tried recording performance in dev tools for both options?

Comment: I tried to provide a new prototype application that contains lots of divs but that didn't result in anything countable. So the general question would be what exactly happens at query/state animations, then we can think further if there are any performance impacts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular uses the [web animations api](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/animations/browser/src/render/web_animations/web_animations_player.ts#L77), so it's not changing style properties through JavaScript and is therefore quite performant. You can check the performance of different animation frameworks (javascript-based) vs CSS with the [HTML 5 Animation Speed Test](https://greensock.com/js/speed.html).

The performance in different browsers is therefore dependent on the browser compatibility of the [web animations api](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API#Browser_compatibility) (unfortunately the section is not being maintained yet). But, according to the comment [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/animations/browser/src/render/web_animations/web_animations_player.ts#L77), it is not fully supported yet across common browsers and is being [polyfilled](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) for Edge/Safari.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting answer but actually it doesn't try to answer my question, as far as I understood you correct. I didn't want to know a speed comparison/estimation of angular animation/web animation itself, I want to know if there is a recommondation in relation to performance (but also other facts if there are some) about do I use queries in angular animation to crawl down the dom tree or do I use states. Are states pre-compiled and therefore I dont need to search for elements and so on... If I need to clarify the question let me know pls.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag Sorry, I didn't figure that out based on your post. Why do compare both approaches? You achieve two different things. In the first approach you apply it to the parent div container, in the second you apply the animation to a child, and then ask about the performance of using animations for n generated children. Is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: I try to find the best possible way to implement animations with angular animations library. Therefore my biggest concern is performance, but also how stable each "kind" of animation is. I will clarify my question. And with both approaches the same animation result can be achieved.

Comment: TL;DR: Don't worry about performance edge cases: Angular animations are really really fast.
---
The question is, if you will ever hit that one edge case where the performance will crash? If you look at the html 5 animation speed test, select the 3000 dots per second and the web animations, you will see how much animations per second it takes to take down chrome. Even with this configuration my machine still achieves 15 fps. If you really want to use more than 3000 animations per second, maybe you should rethink your usecase.

Comment: Answering your performance difference question can only be done looking at the implementation, and I think that's too much of an effort except for the Angular Team

Comment: This question might has a toooo less bounty :) But I appreciate you - This question to answer would require a high amount of effort. But maybe me in the future or someone in the past already had the same thoughts and can answer this. If I am receiving any news or have time to build up a test-environment I will also reply to this question for the sake of maybe some usefull information.

Comment: Thank you for the usefull informations about angular animation in general, but I cannot accept this question as answered, because it doesn't answer the specific question. Nevertheless I appreciate your answer for the important informations you provide us! Thx.

Comment: I accepted the answer because of high community value and in expectation that there will be no more fitting answer for my question.